# Azure AD B2C angular-auth-oidc-client Forgot your password

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c

When clicking "Forgot your password" under b2clogin.com (sign in) page, it seems like it redirects to the same b2c_1_susi flow/profile instead of the b2c_1_reset flow/profile.
I've tried to recreate new AADB2C user flow v2 with no change in results.
Also changing the authWellknownEndpoint or stsServer does not change that.
I guess it's something with AADB2C configuration that I'm doing wrong?

```
oidcConfigService.withConfig({
      stsServer: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0', 
      authWellknownEndpoint:
          'https://xxxxx.b2clogin.com/xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_sisu_v2/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration',
```

....

Would appreciate any help. Cheers!

Comment: You snippet shows `b2c_1_sisu_v2` in `authWellknownEndpoint`, when instead it should be `b2c_1_reset`.
Also when you click forgot password, B2C will send an error back to the App, the App then needs logic to send you to the forgot password flow. See my hello.js [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/apps/blob/master/apps/spa-hellojs-popup/source-code/B2C-v2jsapp/index.html#L159)

Comment: b2c_1_reset will not change that. as far as I understand, it should be handled by AADB2C, but I might be wrong here. This is the code sample I've followed: https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client/blob/master/projects/sample-code-flow-azure-b2c/src/app/app.module.ts#L18

Comment: I'm getting back this error_description=AADB2C90118 I'll try to figure out how to handle it to redirect to reset policy. Thanks. This is the code sample I've followed: https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client/blob/master/projects/sample-code-flow-azure-b2c/src/app/app.module.ts#L18

Comment: Based on the details the error is expected and your app needs to handel it